# Tracking dom-repeat created child nodes, updates in addition to adds/removes

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, dom-repeat

I have a host component that should track information in its child nodes. Child nodes are created using a dom-repeat:

```
<!--host-->
<dom-repeat items="[[data]]">
  <div>...</div>
<dom-repeat>
```

I can track the nodes being added or removed by dom-repeat:

```
//host
attached: function(){
  this_observer = Polymer.dom(this).observeNodes(this._nodesChanged);
}
_nodesChanged: function(info){
  // handle info.addedNodes, info.removedNodes
}
```

But dom-repeat recycles existing nodes when its `items` changes. So, for example, when `data` changes from `[a,b]` to `[c,d]` it will reuse the two existing nodes and therefore _nodesChanged won't be called.

What is a good way for the host component to know when recycled child nodes have been updated? The host component should be able to do so without knowing the inner workings of the child components (encapsulation principle).

Comment: Why not track the data instead of the nodes?

Comment: Yes, that would work in standard cases. I'm thinking about a host component that could work with one or more `dom-repeat`s inside or even nested ones, it would be hard to design the host component to support all such scenarios

Comment: All of the `dom-repeats` (regardless of nesting) would be based on the input `data`, which could be easily observed at multiple levels. It seems like you're trying to solve the wrong problem :)